# Erlang run time environment

Tags: erlang, runtime, environment

Can someone explain what is Erlang run time environment and what dose it contain? Dose it contain erlang VM, what else ?

Regards

MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Erlang runtime environment in particular contains the Erlang virtual machine, the kernel and the standard libraries.

Erlang in general provides a lot more tools (compiler, debugger, monitoring tools etc.).

For details, please have a look at the documentation at: http://www1.erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.8.2/doc/system_architecture_intro/sys_arch_intro.html